# Create table method Android SQLite

Tags: android, sqlite

Is there anything wrong with this table?

```
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACTS + "("
                + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_LAST_NAME + " TEXT," + KEY_MOB_NO + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_HOME_NO + " TEXT," + KEY_WORK_NO + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_HOME_ADDR + " TEXT," + KEY_EMAIL_ADDR + " TEXT,"
                + KEY_WORK_ADDR + " TEXT," + KEY_NOTES + " TEXT" + ");";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
```

My logcat is saying there are no columns. Any idea why this could be?

EDIT: logcat

```
09-28 07:47:48.933: E/SQLiteLog(1908): (1) table contacts has no column named home_address
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908): Error inserting home_address= first_name=543 work_address= mobile_number= work_number= last_name=543 notes= home_number= email_address=
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table contacts has no column named home_address (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO contacts(home_address,first_name,work_address,mobile_number,work_number,last_name,notes,home_number,email_address) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insertWithOnConflict(SQLiteDatabase.java:1467)
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.insert(SQLiteDatabase.java:1339)
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908):     at com.example.contactmanager.DatabaseHandler.addContact(DatabaseHandler.java:80)
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908):     at com.example.contactmanager.NewContactActivity$1.onClick(NewContactActivity.java:63)
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
09-28 07:47:48.953: E/SQLiteDatabase(1908):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your logcat here.

Comment: Did you previously have the same table with fewer columns? If you add more columns later, the database is not upgraded.

Comment: Try removing the semicolon from last.

Comment: I have `;` in my code and it works.

Comment: If you uninstall your app and then run it again, does it work?

Comment: How do I uninstall my app? I have not put it on a smart phone Im just using an emulator on eclipse

Comment: You can uninstall it from the emulator too. It works the same way as on your phone.

Comment: @Szymon thank you, its working after i uninstalled it. Why is this? I spent hours looking for a solution...

Comment: See my edited answer below for explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try uninstalling and running the app again. It may be that you added more columns to the definition and the database was already installed so the new columns were not added. `onCreate` method is run only once when the database is initially installed. It is never run again. When you need to upgrade, there's a separate method `onUpgrade` - but it should be used when you actually release a new version.